# Open a new page with posted variable when the user select the dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

I have this for the dropdown that pulls from the database.
When the user select one of the dropdown, it should open a new page with the posted variable pulled from the dropdown value. how should i approach that with jquery ?

so far i have this

```
 echo '<label><SELECT name="cd-dropdown" id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">'.'<br>';
     echo '<OPTION VALUE="-1" selected>'."Choose Project".'</OPTION>';

     while($row = oci_fetch_array($compCuttingResult,OCI_ASSOC)){
     $projectName = $row ['PROJECT_NAME'];
     echo "<OPTION name='valueSelected' VALUE='$projectName' class='icon-fab'>$projectName</OPTION>";
     }
     echo '</SELECT></label><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<label><SELECT name="cd-dropdown" id="cd-dropdown" onchange="myFunction()" class="cd-select">'.'<br>';
    echo '<OPTION VALUE="-1" selected>'."Choose Project".'</OPTION>';
    echo "<OPTION name='valueSelected' VALUE='test' class='icon-fab'>test</OPTION>";
    echo '</SELECT></label><br />';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){  
    var myselect = document.getElementById("cd-dropdown");
    var val = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location = "https://www.google.co.in/#q="+val;
  }
</script>
```